# Capistrano deploy.rb file based on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I need two deployment files (staging and production); they will have separate deployment details (host, user, environment, branch, etc...). Is it possible to `cap deploy` using a specific file? Something like...

```
cap deploy:staging    # use staging_deploy.rb
cap deploy:production # use production_deploy.rb
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Capistrano 3](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/c1f06cc194406f2938959c0cf6ae003a0f12f54c/README.md) has multi-stage support built-in. For capistrano 2, use an extension: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension.

In both cases, the file structure looks like this:

```
├── Capfile
└── config
    ├── deploy
    │   ├── production.rb
    │   └── staging.rb
    └── deploy.rb
```

You can override settings from `deploy.rb` (host, user and everything else) in a corresponding environment-specific file.

Comment: Use https://github.com/railsware/caphub if you want multi-stage plus multi-app support (when your app is separated into logical repos.)